# Is the webserver OpenSocial requirement a 1 to 1 relationship?

Tags: web-applications, opensocial

For OpenSocial, it requries that you have a separate webserver with a non-self-signed SSL Cert. Can I run one app server for multiple websites or is it always one server per website that will actually be running opensocial?

Also, can the app server be the same server that is hosting the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run all OpenSocial apps for other containers on one server. The seperate webserver for the app isn't required I think.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm looking to create one server so that all of my customers buying an opensocial integration for a particular software wont have to create thier own app server.